Avocado  pruning and potting
This is my second attempt at an avocado plant and I really want to get it right.
It has grown really well indoors but is quite tall at 21 inches approx and only a few months old. I feel I may have missed my window for pruning?
So I have a two part question:

At the moment it is very happy indoors in a jar in water with plant feed - should I move it to soil now (it is october) or leave it in water? Potentially a bigger jar!

Should I prune it or leave it until there are more leaves up top and prune above the lowest one? I am worried if I cut it now, it will die.


I am a complete novice, going from Google! Any advice greatly appreciated :)



Hi Amy, welcome to the site!  I edited your question so your pictures would display properly, and I also removed your gratitude and name - this site has strict rules about keeping the Question post itself pretty business like.  Comments are more open minded.  Good luck with your plant, it looks happy!

Thank you for your help. I did get a bit stuck adding in the pictures.

Are you in a region where it can be expected to grow outside? If not, are you prepared to deal with a Very Large Potted Plant in the house? It's a tree, it wants to be a tree, and unless you go down the path of Bonsai with it (which is a difficult undertaking in itself) it will get huge.

If you live in a climate where it freezes during the Winter, then putting it outside will almost certainly kill it before Spring comes. If you only have very light frosts that don't last more than a couple hours then you might be able to protect it by covering it on cold nights, but it is still likely to do much better indoors where it's warmer. Once it gets bigger, it might be able to tolerate a little bit more cold.
Check what zone you are in using https://planthardiness.ars.usda.gov/ and enter your zip code. Chance of survival falls quickly for avocados planted below zone 9b. It's a crap shoot for avocados grown from the pit because avocados have a wide variety of genetic possibilities due to a large gene pool and you won't know up front how cold tolerant it will be.
If you keep it indoors, you could pot it in very well drained fertile potting soil, but make sure you water it a lot and put it where it will get the most sun. I wouldn't prune it until it grows more leaves. It should start making side buds that will turn into side branches. If it doesn't, then only take the tip of it off to stop the apical dominance. This will force the natural growth hormones to encourage the lower branches to grow out.
Also, you might consider using a stake because that little guy is pretty lanky. It's growing too quickly and needs more light.
